# Can't get WebSockets to work on the same port as the http server

Tags: express, websocket

I have this dead simple websocket connection logic

```
const server = http.createServer(app)
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', (message) => {

      console.log('received: %s', message);
      ws.send(`Hello, you sent -> ${message}`);
  });

  ws.send('Hi there, I am a WebSocket server');
});
```

This returns `The websocket has not connected to the server`

But if I change the WebSocket.Server config to a different port it is all good.

e.g. `const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 3002 });`

I have not been able to replicate the issue sadly

Comment: Did you call `server.listen(3002)` on the http server to actually start the http server?